# Oil gauge jumps up and down when the motor gets hot and it’s getting hot quickly

Tags: chevrolet, oil, pressure, gauges, fluid-level

Oil pressure goes up and down when my c2500 gets hot and it’s been getting hot quickly the hot part is the head gasket why the oil gauge

Comment: How quickly is the oil pressures going up and down?  Every few seconds,?

Comment: Have you checked the oil level recently?  Have you checked if there is emulsion in the oil?